# How to convert RGB to YUV in tensorflow?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tensorflow, color-space

How can one convert an RGB image into YUV with tensorflow? 
This is a sample implementation of RGB to LAB but I have trouble defining the same for the YUV color space. I have tried using the last part with the YUV/RGB matrix respectively but get dimension errors:

```
# based on https://github.com/torch/image/blob/9f65c30167b2048ecbe8b7befdc6b2d6d12baee9/generic/image.c
def rgb_to_lab(srgb):
    with tf.name_scope("rgb_to_lab"):
        srgb = check_image(srgb)
        srgb_pixels = tf.reshape(srgb, [-1, 3])

        with tf.name_scope("srgb_to_xyz"):
            linear_mask = tf.cast(srgb_pixels <= 0.04045, dtype=tf.float32)
            exponential_mask = tf.cast(srgb_pixels > 0.04045, dtype=tf.float32)
            rgb_pixels = (srgb_pixels / 12.92 * linear_mask) + (((srgb_pixels + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4) * exponential_mask
            rgb_to_xyz = tf.constant([
                #    X        Y          Z
                [0.412453, 0.212671, 0.019334], # R
                [0.357580, 0.715160, 0.119193], # G
                [0.180423, 0.072169, 0.950227], # B
            ])
            xyz_pixels = tf.matmul(rgb_pixels, rgb_to_xyz)

        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space#CIELAB-CIEXYZ_conversions
        with tf.name_scope("xyz_to_cielab"):
            # convert to fx = f(X/Xn), fy = f(Y/Yn), fz = f(Z/Zn)

            # normalize for D65 white point
            xyz_normalized_pixels = tf.multiply(xyz_pixels, [1/0.950456, 1.0, 1/1.088754])

            epsilon = 6/29
            linear_mask = tf.cast(xyz_normalized_pixels <= (epsilon**3), dtype=tf.float32)
            exponential_mask = tf.cast(xyz_normalized_pixels > (epsilon**3), dtype=tf.float32)
            fxfyfz_pixels = (xyz_normalized_pixels / (3 * epsilon**2) + 4/29) * linear_mask + (xyz_normalized_pixels ** (1/3)) * exponential_mask

            # convert to lab
            fxfyfz_to_lab = tf.constant([
                #  l       a       b
                [  0.0,  500.0,    0.0], # fx
                [116.0, -500.0,  200.0], # fy
                [  0.0,    0.0, -200.0], # fz
            ])
            lab_pixels = tf.matmul(fxfyfz_pixels, fxfyfz_to_lab) + tf.constant([-16.0, 0.0, 0.0])

        return tf.reshape(lab_pixels, tf.shape(srgb))
```

This is what I have done so far but I get dimension errors in `split`. `check_image` checks the number of channels:

```
def rgb_to_yuv(rgb):
    with tf.name_scope("rgb_to_yuv"):
        rgb_pixels = check_image(rgb)
        #rgb_pixels = tf.reshape(rgb, [-1, 3])
        print (tf.rank(rgb_pixels))
        r , g, b= tf.split(rgb_pixels, 3, 1)
        Y = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b
        U = 0.492 * (b - Y)
        V = 0.877 * (r - Y)
        yuv_pixels = tf.concat([Y, U, V], 1)
        return tf.reshape(yuv_pixels, tf.shape(rgb))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried translating this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/jni/rgb2yuv.cc?

Comment: @m3h0w, I am not sure how to deal with shift instructions in python

Comment: What is the shape of the `rgb_pixels` tensor? Typically I'd expect it to be `height` x `width` x `channels`, so you'd want to split on axis 2.

Comment: Did you try using tf.images.rgb_to_yuv ?